# Angular module creates a singleton service with app scope - Angular 14

Tags: angular

As Angular guide says:

> Providing a singleton service.
> There are two ways to make a service a singleton in Angular:
>
> Set the providedIn property of the @Injectable() to "root"
> Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only imported by the AppModule

I created the list-courses.module that inject the courses.service, but it is imported only by orders.module, not by AppModule.

Why does create-courses.module use the same instance of courses.service?

Code in Github:
https://github.com/danilobatistaqueiroz/ng-singleton-service

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### Using the service in more than one module:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm getting a singleton even if adding the service in more than one module.

---

### Using Lazy Load Modules:

I updated the project to use lazy loaded modules, and it still load a singleton service.

https://github.com/danilobatistaqueiroz/ng-lazyload-singleton-service

---

Comment: Danilo, if you use `{provideIn:root}` it's singleton to all the aplicacion. You can also use `{provideIn:ListCourseModule}` and only use this module. You can use `providers:[CoursesService]` in a module or in a component and Angular create different instances to each Module/Component.

Comment: @Eliseo, my question is exactly about this. It doesn't work as you said. I have singleton even if I use providers:[CoursesService] in more than one module.

Comment: If you want a new instance, you have to provide it at component level.